# list problem in c#. how to do this in c#

Tags: c#

i have a list of struct

list who have a detail of stuff.

i need a another string info with this list.

so i wrote many function already who is used in my project

so i make a new list

who called stuffdetailedanother

who have a stuffdetailed stuff
and string info;

but when i send it to page using viewdata then he not worked when i use immediate window everything is fine.

are any another way i use ?

or how to pass him to a control

i pass it by a way

controller > View > Partial view

but it is not worked

i got the error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Source Error:

Line 347:            #line default
Line 348:            #line hidden
Line 349:            @__w.Write("\r\n    </div>\r\n</div>\r\n");
Line 350:        }
Line 351:        


Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2114142c\1d077c0d\App_Web_wishproductlist.ascx.89207646.1grmjmuq.0.cs    Line: 349
```

Comment: @Dave, I was going through the post seriously and then I came across your comment. Can't stop laughing... yes it seems like a poem. +1 to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the following line:

```
@__w.Write("\r\n    </div>\r\n</div>\r\n");
```

(Line 349 in App_Web_wishproductlist.ascx.cs) contains a syntax error - probably the `@` symbol.

Without knowing more context its difficult to know what other advice to give, however hopefully this helps make the error a little clearer.

Comment: @4thpage - Try running `iisreset` and empty the contents of the ASP.Net temporary files folder.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have a syntax error on line 351 of your ASPX file.  Take a closer look at it.  If you don't understand why it's not compiling, post the code.